# Getting Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, html

I keep on getting this error  Uncaught ReferenceError: calculatePrice is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick.

I have already seen the other answers on here regarding this error and none of them worked. I tried defining the script in body or head, didn't make a difference. I also think the function and button I connect it to are correct as I compared to a solution, so I really don't know why it is not working when I press it.

```
<html>
    <head> 
      <link href="style/myStyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
          <title> The Printing Company </title> 
    </head>
     <body>
     <script type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
        function calculatePrice() {
            var quantity, type, price 
            quantity = document.getElementById("qty").value;
            type = document.getElementById("cardstype").value;
            if (type.includes("Basic"){
                price = 10*(quantity/100);
            } else if (type.includes("Medium"){
                price = 15*(quantity/100);
            } else if (type.includes("High"){
                price = 20*(quantity/100);
            }
            alert("Your order will cost " + price + " GBP.");
          }
        </script>

        <form action="form.php" method="post">
                 <label >Company Name</label><br>
                 <input name="name" type="text" required /><br>
                 <br>
                 <label>Contact email</label><br>
                 <input name="email" type="email" required /><br>
                 <br>
                 <label>Business Card type</label><br>
                 <select name="cardstype" id="cardstype">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>-Select Card Quality-</option>
                    <option value="Basic Quality">Basic Quality</option>
                    <option value="Medium Quality">Medium Quality</option>
                    <option value="High Quality">High Quality</option>
                 </select><br>
                 <br>
                 <label>Business Cards quantity</label><br>
                 <input name="qty" id ="qty" type="number" required  Onchange = '
                        if( !( this.value >= 100 && this.value <= 1000 ) ) {
                            //alert the user that they have made a mistake
                            alert( this.value + " is not a valid quantity. Minimun quantity per order: 100 and maximum: 1000.");
                            this.value=""; //clears the text box
                        }'><br>
                 <br>
                 <input type="button" name="Price" value="Calculate Price" onclick="calculatePrice()"/>
                 <input type="submit" value="Submit Order"/>
            </form>
    </html>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Voting to close this, as a question about a simple typo won't be of help to other users.

Comment: Hi, sorry i fixed the spelling mistake but it didnt fix anything

Comment: Oh, there's a bunch more typos, actually, I'll edit my answer to point them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You are missing the closing parentheses in your if statements:

```
if (type.includes("Basic") {
                          ^^^ here
```

Working example:

```js
function calculatePrice() {

    var quantity, type, price;
    quantity = document.getElementById("qty").value;
    type = document.getElementById("cardstype").value;

    if (type.includes("Basic")) {
        price = 10*(quantity/100);
    } else if (type.includes("Medium")) {
        price = 15*(quantity/100);
    } else if (type.includes("High")) {
        price = 20*(quantity/100);
    }

    alert("Your order will cost " + price + " GBP.");

}
```

```html
    <form action="form.php" method="post">
             <label >Company Name</label><br>
             <input name="name" type="text" required /><br>
             <br>
             <label>Contact email</label><br>
             <input name="email" type="email" required /><br>
             <br>
             <label>Business Card type</label><br>
             <select name="cardstype" id="cardstype">
                <option value="" disabled selected>-Select Card Quality-</option>
                <option value="Basic Quality">Basic Quality</option>
                <option value="Medium Quality">Medium Quality</option>
                <option value="High Quality">High Quality</option>
             </select><br>
             <br>
             <label>Business Cards quantity</label><br>
             <input name="qty" id ="qty" type="number" required  Onchange = '
                    if( !( this.value >= 100 && this.value <= 1000 ) ) {
                        //alert the user that they have made a mistake
                        alert( this.value + " is not a valid quantity. Minimun quantity per order: 100 and maximum: 1000.");
                        this.value=""; //clears the text box
                    }'><br>
             <br>
             <input type="button" name="Price" value="Calculate Price" onclick="calculatePrice(event)"/>
             <input type="submit" value="Submit Order"/>
        </form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much..seen my silly mistake over edits

Comment: @Codingnooby Glad it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few typos in your function:

- Missing closing curly brace (looks fixed now)
- Missing semicolon after variable definition: `var quantity, type, price;`
- Mismatched parentheses in if/elseif conditions (3 times): `if (type.includes("Basic")) {`

The below code has these problems fixed:

```
<script>
function calculatePrice() {
    var quantity, type, price;
    quantity = document.getElementById("qty").value;
    type = document.getElementById("cardstype").value;
    if (type.includes("Basic")){
        price = 10*(quantity/100);
    } else if (type.includes("Medium")){
        price = 15*(quantity/100);
    } else if (type.includes("High")){
        price = 20*(quantity/100);
    }
    alert("Your order will cost " + price + " GBP.");
}
</script>
```

Therefore, the function calculatePrice isn't defined and can't be called.

Comment: Hi, sorry i fixed the spelling mistake but it didnt fix anything

Comment: Semicolons are optional now in javascript